# single linked-list error in c

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

ma fellow geek,
i've created single linked list algorithm, but i didnt see it work properly :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
  typedef struct _data_konfirm
    {
        char *id;
        char *buff;
        int v;

        struct _data_konfirm *next;
    }data_konfirm;

 void data_add(data_konfirm **data,char *id,char *buff,int v)
{
    data_konfirm *tmp = (data_konfirm*)malloc(sizeof(data_konfirm));
    tmp->id             = strdup(id);
    tmp->buff           = strdup(buff);
    tmp->v = v;

    tmp->next = *data;
    *data = tmp;    
}

void data_destroy(data_konfirm **data)
{
        data_konfirm *b = *data;
        free(b->id);
        free(b->buff);
        free(b);
}

void data_del(data_konfirm **data,char *id)
{


    data_konfirm *tmp = *data, *b = NULL;

    if(!strcmp(tmp->id,id))
    {
        b = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        data_destroy(&b);              
        return;
    }


    while(tmp->next->next != NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp(tmp->next->id,id))
        {
            b = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = b->next;
            data_destroy(&b);

            return;
        }

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if(!strcmp(tmp->next->id,id))
    {
        b = tmp->next;
        data_destroy(&b);
        tmp->next = NULL;
        return;        
    }


}

void inform_show_all(data_konfirm **data)
{        
    data_konfirm *tmp = *data;
    int i = 0;
    while(tmp)
    {
        printf("id              -> %s\n",tmp->id);
        printf("buff            -> %s\n",tmp->buff);        
        i++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    printf("jumlah data : %d\n",i);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    data_konfirm *a = NULL;

    data_add(&a,"1","silit",2);
    data_del(&a,"1");
    data_add(&a,"2","wwww",1);
    data_add(&a,"3","zzz",2);
    data_add(&a,"4","huaaa",2);

    data_del(&a,"3");

    inform_show_all(&a);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

if i run these code, the loop will never end, whats wrong then ?

thank in advance...

Comment: -1: Did you try stepping through your code in a debugger?  Or adding printf statements to see how the program is flowing?

Comment: i did(debug,printf,re-code,etc..), and investigate it in last 4 hours to getting understand, and these question is one of all the chance that i got to get understand single linked-list

Comment: Also, don't forget to include string.h.

Comment: i oft to ignore implicit warning from gcc, because i thought it never make different for the result, am i right sir ?

Comment: its look like loop and print only second row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function data_del substitute

```
b = tmp;
tmp = tmp->next;
```

with

```
b = *data;
*data = (*data)->next;
```

Here is a picture of the situation:

```
*data -> +---+           +---+
  tmp -> | | | -> ... -> | | |
    b -> +---+           +---+
```

The statement tmp = tmp->next will not update the pointer *data.

Comment: it work, but i just dont get it , why use `*data` instead of `tmp` ?

Comment: @capede Because tmp will not update the pointer *data which is what you want. If you draw the list with its pointers you will understand.

Comment: It is the second line that matters.  `b = tmp` and b = `*data` are equivalent, but you need to update through `*data`, as August said.

Comment: @andrewdski Indeed, but I think it is cleaner not to involve more variables than you need in the "delete first" case.

Comment: im so sorry sir, but honestly, i dont get it by your-picture-situation-based, all i get is, `if first case it need update by direct pointer`

Comment: @capede After the statement tmp = tmp->next the pointer *data will still point to the same element. This element is then freed with data_destroy. That's why your code was broken.

Comment: mmm do you mean `tmp = tmp->next;` movement had nothing todo with `*data`-updating-data, because after `movement` tmp changed address to somewhere, and `*data` had still no changed address, i see ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't like just providing code, but that `data_del` function is a mess.  Try this:

```
void data_del(data_konfirm **data,char *id)
{
    while( *data != NULL )
    {
        data_konfirm* tmp = *data;
        if( strcmp( tmp->id, id ) == 0 )
        {
            *data = tmp->next;  /* remove tmp from list */
            data_destroy( &tmp );
            break;
        }

        data = &tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Fair warning, I haven't actually tested this.

Comment: hell no, it's work though -_-'

Comment: (I apologize for going into teacher-mode here.)  But do you understand it?  Deleting is definitely the hard part with singly linked lists.  The key is to keep `*data` pointing at the pointer that got us to `tmp` so we can point it at `tmp->next` thus splicing `tmp` out of the list.

Comment: ahh i get it sir, these more understandable than **delete first head with direct pointer**

Answer (score 0):

If your `data_del` function needs to delete the list's head node, it won't set the head to the next element, so you will be left with a pointer to a freed node. What you should do is set `*data` to the new head in that case.

You also have a problem with  `data_del` not working with empty lists: it will try accessing a null pointer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This bit at the start of `data_del` can't be right:

```
if(!strcmp(tmp->id,id))
{
    b = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next;
    data_destroy(&b);              
    return;
}
```

When you enter this block you delete the first item in the list but don't update the head pointer.

I would not be surprised for there to be other problems in the code.